# Is it possible to query collectionGroup on a specific collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a user collection, and within that collection there's a collection name groups, which then has groupItems. Is it possible to run a query for all groupItems for a specific user?

I could run a global version like:

```
db.collectionGroup('groupItems')
```

but that is overkill for me, I'm looking for something like:

```
db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('groups').collectionGroup('groupIems').where('categoryOnly', '==', true)
```

Is this possible?

The architecture of the collections looks like this:

```
Users
---> User
------> Collections
---------> GroupA
------------> GroupAItems
---------------> GroupAItem1
---------------> GroupAItem2
---------> GroupB
------------> GroupBItems
---------------> GroupBItem1
---------------> GroupBItem2
```

Ideally I could call for all Group Items instead of first calling for groups and getting [GroupA, GroupB...], and then calling for GroupA's items, then GroupB's, etc.

Comment: Did you just tried out if it's working?

Comment: Yeah. The call I have as-is is returning that the function does not exist.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to reconsider the naming of your subcollections so that they're easier to query with a collection group query.  As it stands now, your data requires multiple queries to get everything you need.

Comment: I think the workaround is to add the user's uid to each group item, then a where condition looking for that uid on a collectiongroup query should work.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: it turns out that querying a specific path may be possible after all, thanks to how `FieldPath.documentId()` is indexed for collection group indexes. Check @samthecodingman's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049847

Happy answer above

---

Old answer below

There is currently no way to limit a collection group to just collections under a specific path. All collection group queries get documents from all collections with the specified name.

So the only way to currently query a subset of your groups is to use a naming scheme that allows you to uniquely address them.

Also see:

- [Does collection group queries get data from all collections with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217606/does-collection-group-queries-get-data-from-all-collections-with-the-same-name)
- [collectionGroup within a certain path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934947/collectiongroup-within-a-certain-path)